# Approach to download files through POST request

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, form, ajax

I have a requirement to download multiple files using POST request. So I am using form submit to get this done.

I have followed two approaches to accomplish this.

1. Create a Form. Fill input details with payload data. Then set the target of the Form to `_self` then manually submit the Form. But I see few problems with this approach. Like, When payload is incorrect or Server has download API problems the current page will be redirected to 404 page.

   ```
   var method = "POST";
   var form = document.createElement("form");
   form.setAttribute("method", method);
   form.setAttribute("action", "https://some-url");
   appendFormData(form, options.data.items);
   document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.submit();
   document.body.removeChild(form);
   ```

2) Second approach is similar to the first one, except that I am creating an iframe, appending it to DOM and providing iframe as the target for Form. This works but the problem is, I am not sure when to remove the iFrame from the DOM.

```
    var method = "POST";
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "hidden-frame");
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var iDocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var form = iDocument.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", "https://some-url");
    form.setAttribute("target", "hidden-frame");
    appendFormData(form, options.data.items);
    iDocument.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
```

Can you please suggest ways to improve the above solution or suggest if there are any better approach to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
iframe.addEventListener('loadend', function() {
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
});
```

The iframe has many other events (`load`, `error`, `abort`, `progress`) which might also be useful.

Comment: I tried `load` and `loadend` events which are not working. load will be called when iframe is appended to `dom` but not when form is submitted and `loadend` is not even triggered(According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadend) `loadend` will be called only for iframe content and XMLHttpRequest not for form submit)